# Is the series convergence or divergence

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Does $\displaystyle \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{n^{n}}{e^{2n}n!}$ converge?

---

I tried with Comparison test so that $0<\frac{n^{n}}{e^{2n}n!}<\frac{n^{n}}{n!}$

And $\frac{n^{n}}{n!}$ converges to $1$ with ratio test. So the orginal series should converges? I think my solution is wrong.

Comment: $\frac{n^{n}}{n!} \ge 1$ (and itself diverges to $+\infty$) so $\sum \frac{n^{n}}{n!}$ will not converge and does not help.  I would try Stirling's approximation

Comment: We did not go through this kind of approximation. Is there any other way?

Comment: @Henry above ^^^

Comment: If you are going to use the ratio test, take the ratio of successive terms.  Don't forget the $e^{2n}$

Comment: @Henry, ratio test gives me a value of $\displaystyle \frac{1}{e^{2}}$ so the series is convergent?

Comment: If the ratio of consecutive terms did have a limit below $1$ then the series would be convergent.  But $\frac{1}{e^2}$ looks wrong to me

Comment: @Henry, but the ratio test gives us: the limit as n approach zero: $\displaystyle \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\frac{n^{(n+1)}}{e^{2(n+1)} \cdot (n+1)!} \cdot \frac{e^{2n} \cdot n!}{n^n}=... =\frac{1}{e^2}$

Comment: That should be $(n+1)^{(n+1)}$ rather than $n^{(n+1)}$ and makes a difference of about $e$

Comment: I got now $\displaystyle \lim \frac{a_n+1}{a_n}=...=\lim ({\frac{n+1}{n}})^{n} \cdot \frac{1}{e^2}$ Same because $\lim ({\frac{n+1}{n}})^{n}$ is $=1$ as n--->$\infty$ :(

Comment: @Henry above^^^^

Comment: $\lim \left({\frac{n+1}{n}}\right)^{n}$ is not $1$ but $e$.  Indeed it is a possible definition of $e$

Comment: It still converge then? since we got $\displaystyle \frac{1}{e}$

Comment: @Henry above ^^^^

Comment: Yes - it converges, for that reason.  The sum is about $1.188487$